# Product prices show only after login

Tags: magento2, product, price, login, catalog-price-rules

I have a special requirement for my website. Please see the following point and provide me an appropriate suggestion on how to do this.

Requirements:

1. A user sees the product price only after logging in.
2. Product price is different according to their user group.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. A user sees the product price only after login.

   - **You can achieve this kind of functionality using any third party extension.
     ex : https://store.webkul.com/Show-Price-After-Login-For-Magento2.html**
2. Product price is different according to a user group.

   - **Magento 2 have concept of tier pricing where you can set different price for different customer group here is the reference link how to set different price for different customer group - https://www.customerparadigm.com/how-do-i-set-group-specific-product-pricing-to-a-customer-group-in-magento-2/**

Comment: Thanks for quick reply.

As per your reference 
Can you please clarify. If I am not added Tier Price Quantity then what will happen?

Comment: @Chetan - Generally Tier price is used for giving bulk purchase discount for specific customer , so if you want to do it for single product with single quantity , give 1 as an qty. you need to give qty

Comment: Ok, but as per my requirement, for example, we have three user group A, B and C  So product price is different for each and every user group

Comment: I want to add price filter on user groups

Comment: Yes you can do the same from tier pricing - add 3 times tier pricing for product and select group each time and give gty 1 for each and give price to  3 of them differently, hope you got it